# sqlite3.OperationalError: unable to open database file, pyrogram

Tags: python, linux, telegram-bot, pyrogram

У меня проблемы в хостинге:
`sqlite3.OperationalError: unable to open database file`
прикол весь в том что ошибка в библиотеке `pyrogram` (да в доках есть ссылка на такую ошибку, но видимо я тупой и не понял или не умею так руководить сервером, чтобы узнать все что надо*)
на пк все работает идеально и да хост это `pythonanywhere`.
С чем связана эта проблема? И как можно её решить?

[image: _]

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: Может поможет: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4636970/sqlite3-operationalerror-unable-to-open-database-file